# Trouble with Sub-Classes and Inheritence

Tags: java, class, subclass, superclass

So imagine I have a Superclass `Staff` which has generic variables such as Name, address etc.
There are 4 subclasses `Doctor`, `Nurse`, `Receptionist` and `OfficeManager` each with unique variables and methods.
The problem with this set up is, a `Doctor` can also be an `OfficeManager` for example, so would need access to the variables and methods in `OfficeManager`
Is there a way an instance of Doctor can have access to methods in `OfficeManager`?
Is having `Staff` as a superclass and the 4 subclasses an ideal design?

Any other ideas would be appreciated.

ps. I haven't started drawing up the code as I still don't know the design stage, ie Classes.

Comment: _generic variables_? Be careful with keywords when you describe your problem.

Comment: Yeah I mean just like standard variables, something all the subclasses have in common.

Comment: How would you use that? Would you have an array of staff objects and cast them to Doctor to use the `curePeople()` method or to OfficeManager to use the `manageOffice()` method? Will they have unique **public** methods, or just unique private methods and different implementations of the same public methods? What is this design for?

Comment: @user3074612 There is concept in Java called `generics`, which you might get introduced to later. Keppil meant that you should use the word generic only when it deals with Java generics.

Comment: So for example, a doctor will have extra variables; patients, prescriptions, etc and an Office Manager would have a method manageRecords()

Comment: A doctor who is also an Office Manager would also need to be able to run manageRecords()

Comment: I think you should treat roles and people as different entities. So (example) a role could have a list of people or a person could have a list of roles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If several subclasses need the same functionality, that functionality should be moved either to the Staff class or some level between Staff and e.g. Doctor. It depends on the functionality and intent. The subclasses should not be aware of each other though, that kind of ruins the whole idea.

Answer (score 1):

If a `Doctor` can also be a `OfficeManager` they should definitely be interfaces. That way you can have something like:

```
public class VeryImportantPerson implements Doctor, OfficeManager {
```

Otherwise your approach with a `Staff` interface and 4 other ones extending them sounds just fine.

Comment: This way every new role combination should be created in code and not runtime? Beware of that!

Answer (score 0):

Use interfaces. Have your interface require that you implement get methods for each one of the properties that you wish to have in common among your classes. You can then implement multiple interface in a concrete or even an abstract class.

Answer (score 0):

If a class can be both a Doctor and an OfficeManager, then they shouldn't be classes. You might make them interfaces.

Alternatively, you might change your class hierarchy to represent *responsibilities* instead of people. Then you could have a Person class that contains a List of responsibilities.

Answer (score 0):

You should create an ENUM called ROLE which has enum values like: DOCTOR, NURSE, OFFICE_MANAGER, and an instance of a Staff should hold a set of ROLEs.

This way for example in a method that is found in Staff class you can:

```
public void fireEveryoneAndSetTheBuildingOnFire(){
    if(!thisPersonHoldsOfficeManagerRole()){
        // Exception here.. Required role not found..
    }

    fireEveryone();
    setTheBuildingOnFire();
}
```

Comment: perhaps you should elaborate on how you would implement this. Right now, this is a bit too short to be a real answer

Answer (score 0):

Create an interface for each subclass , with the functions it can do , that when you create a class of a doctor implements the "Manager" Interface , it will have access to the manager functions
if you need something more complex , you might want to reconsider the hierarchy 
like , for example

```
*Staff
 -management
    *Manager
    *recieption

  -practioner
    *doctor
    *nurse
```

Answer (score -2):

Maybe think about the jobs themselves as roles that can decorate a staff object.